# Choice of a dense subset of a separable Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, topological-groups, banach-algebras

I recently came across the following statement, and still can't prove it:

Statement: Suppose $X$ is a separable,closed subspace of $L^1(G)$, where $G$ is a locally compact group. Since $X$ is separable, there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which spans a dense subspace of $X$ and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}||x_n||=0$,

My problem is that I feel this statement is false: Suppose such a sequence exists. Then you can find $N$ such that $||x_n||<1$ for all $n>N$. Let $M=\max\{||x_1||,\cdots,||x_N||\}$. Then any element outside the ball of radius $M+1$ can't be "close" to any $x_n$, and hence $x_n$'s can't be dense. Can someone explain to me if my reasoning is correct, or if there is a flaw somewhere. Also, if my reasoning is incorrect and the original statement is true- I would appreciate a hint towards the proof.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.

Comment: The claim is not that $\{x_n\}$ is dense in $X$, but that the linear span of $\{x_n\}$ is dense in $X.$

Comment: Isn't the statement true? I'm pretty sure in any separable normed vector space, you can find a countable set $\{x_n\}$ which is dense and thus spans a dense subspace. And then consider the vectors $\frac{x_n}{n||x_n||}$, which span the same dense subspace. As zhw pointed out, you proved that the collection $\{x_n\}$ is not dense, not that its **span** is not dense.

Comment: @zhw.: Ah. Your and Shalop's statements helped me understand what I was missing.

Comment: @Shalop: Thanks. So your statement actually proves the above statement-right?

Comment: Thanks again for your help.